Failing to load a custom world file in Gazebo with roslaunch
I am trying to launch a custom world in Gazebo and I get:

Error [parser.cc:386] Error finding file [/home/devadm/.gazebo/models/environment/model.sdf].


Error Code 1 Msg: Unable to read file[/home/devadm/.gazebo/models/environment/model.sdf]


Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element world


Error Code 8 Msg: Error reading element sdf


[Err] [Server.cc:479] Unable to read sdffile[/home/devadm/rmtp_ws/src/amr/worlds/ambiente.world]

The ambiente.world file is defined as :

<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <sdf version="1.7">   
 <world name="world">
<include>
    <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
</include>
<include>
    <uri>model://sun</uri>
</include>
<include>
    <uri>model://environment</uri>
</include>
</world> 
</sdf>


Point is that I defined the model environment into a package, the same package that hosts the ambiente.world file. I've also add the export tag in the package.xml as
  <export>
    <gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="/home/devadm/rmtp_ws/src/amr/models"/>
    <gazebo_ros gazebo_media_path="/home/devadm/rmtp_ws/src/amr/models"/>
  </export>

Clearly the package is called amr and contains these folders: models and worlds.
I've also add these lines to my .bashrc file:

export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/.gazebo/models


export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/rmtp_ws/src/amr/models


export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH:~/rmtp_ws/src/amr/worlds

How can I solve this problem?
EDIT 1: I removed

export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:~/.gazebo/models

but now when launching it doesn't load anything and I get the warning:

[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""]
[model://environment]

EDIT 2: The structure of packages and folders is as follows:

home/devadm/
─ rmtp_ws

 ─ src

  ─ amr

    ─ models

       ─ model.sdf

       ─ meodel.config

       ─ mesh.stl

       ─ mesh.dae



There's some more info on the model:// URI here and here.
I tend to rather write the (relative) path to the sdf file of my model instead:
    <include>
      <uri>sdf/my_model.sdf</uri>
      <pose degrees="true">21.5 -1.5 0 0 0 90</pose>
    </include>


Tried with sdf/ but doesn't work...

I think you might have misinterpreted the example: sdf/ is just a subfolder in which I place my sdf files. In your case, you rather need something like <uri>src/amr/models/ground_plane.sdf</uri>.

Tried to do as you said, still doesn't work and I get the error: Error Code 11 Msg: Invalid uri[rmtp_ws/src/amr/models/environment.sdf]. Should be model://rmtp_ws/src/amr/models/environment.sdf
Obviuosly I tried as suggested and it still doesn't work

Can you edit your question and post an exact directory/file structure (similar to the example in section Path relative to the SDF file)? Also, to rule out the obvious: it is Gazebo Classic, and not Gazebo Sim, right?

Check the edit. Thanks for your time.

I don't see environment.sdf in your directory tree?

the file is named model.sdf and the name of the model is environment.

It does not work like that. You specify names to files or directories. It does not scan those files for models inside them.
